java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNs
I am getting following exceptions in gradle ant.xjc. its working perfectly when it has
generate("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1") as a dependency.
Execution failed for task ':createWsdlSource'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNs

Gradle task:
task 'createWsdlSource' {
    group 'nab build'

    def wsdlDir = 'src/main/resources/wsdls'
    def wsdlFiles = [
            "abc/1xx.wsdl",
            "abc/2xx.wsdl"
    ]
    def commonXsdFiles = [
            "dp/xjb/Misc.xjb",
            "dp/xjb/Header.xjb",
            "dp/xjb/Common.xjb"
    ]
    def xsdFiles = [
            [name: "dp/xsd/retrieveDirectDebitArrangement.xsd", binding: "dp/xjb/retrieveDirectDebitArrangement.xjb"],
            [name: "dp/xsd/updateDirectDebitArrangement.xsd", binding: "dp/xjb/updateDirectDebitArrangement.xjb"]
    ]

    inputs.dir("${projectDir}/${wsdlDir}")
    outputs.dir("${buildDir}/generated/wsdl")

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'wsimport', classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport', classpath: configurations.generate.asPath)
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.generate.asPath)

        System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'file')

        wsdlFiles.each {
            def wsdl = project.file("${wsdlDir}/${it}")
            ant.wsimport(wsdl: project.file(wsdl), sourcedestdir: outputs.files.singleFile, keep: true, xnocompile: true, xadditionalHeaders: true, extension: true)
        }

        xsdFiles.each { xsd ->
            ant.xjc(destdir: outputs.files.singleFile, schema: "$wsdlDir/$xsd.name", extension: true) {
                binding(dir: "$wsdlDir", includes: commonXsdFiles.get(0))
                binding(dir: "$wsdlDir", includes: commonXsdFiles.get(1))
                binding(dir: "$wsdlDir", includes: xsd.binding)
                classpath(path: configurations.xjc.asPath)
                arg(value: '-Xnamespace-prefix')
            }
        }

    }
}

Gradle Dependency:
dependencies{

    generate("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:${jakartaVersion}")
    generate("jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:${jakartaVersion}")
    generate("jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0")

    generate("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:4.0.5")
    generate("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:${jaxwsVersion}")
    generate("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:${jaxwsVersion}")

    xjc(group: 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons', name: 'jaxb2-namespace-prefix', version: '1.3')

Build environment : JDK 17 and Gradle 8.3
jakartaVersion = '4.0.2'
jaxwsVersion = '4.0.2'
Could you please someone help on this ?

Can you add enough source code to simulate the missing class?

The problem is that the following dependency use jaxb-api 2.x and you're targeting jakarta with jaxb-api 4.x
    xjc(group: 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons', name: 'jaxb2-namespace-prefix', version: '1.3')

In order for you to solve your problem, you could use the equivalent in jaxb-tools :
    xjc(group: 'org.jvnet.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-plugins', version: '4.O.8')

See documentation of the plugin here and how to use the plugins here
